# Should a sound be capitalized or punctuated with "!" in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, quotation-marks, exclamation-mark

> He ran fast as the wind out of the cave when the rock went "clunk" on his head.

I am not sure how to write clunk here.

...went "Clunk!" on his head.
...went "clunk" on his head.
...went "Clunk" on his head.

Comment: There is no rule about this, but as the rock didn't speak I would suggest dropping the inverted commas and the capital letter and just saying 'the rock went _clunk_'.

Answer (score 1):

"Clunk" is [also a verb, per Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clunk), meaning to make a "clunk" sound; it can also be a noun for the sound itself. So I think the most idiomatic way to use "clunk" would be:

> ...when the rock **clunked** his head.

Or:

> ...when the rock hit his head with a **clunk.**

If you prefer one of the above three, I think "clunk" (all lowercase) is best, though I don't think there's a consistent rule for this.

Comment: Seems rather opinion based. Recommended action is to remove "i think" statements and word it more generally, and qualifications like "best" which can be expressed in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you could probably get away with putting it in italics, since it's onomatopoeia.

> He ran fast as the wind out of the cave when the rock went *clunk* on his head.

Another option for italics would be to add an exclamation point.

> He ran fast as the wind out of the cave when the rock went *clunk!* on his head.

As stated by [thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Exclamation-Points.htm#:%7E:text=When%20we%20use%20onomatopoeias%20(words,put%20such%20words%20in%20italics.)), "When we use onomatopoeias (words that phonetically imitate particular sounds), we can emphasize the intensity of the sound by putting an exclamation point immediately after it. (It is also common practice to put such words in italics.)"

If you're not looking to use italics (for whatever reason), I'd suggest all lowercase. Your first example was correct.

I'd recommend reading the last section in [this article from thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/when-should-you-use-italics/#:%7E:text=Onomatopoeic%20words%20or%20words%20that,it%20should%20also%20be%20italicized) for more information about italicizing onomatopoeic words.

Comment: Not all formats support italics. Recommended action is address that in some way.